# I cloned a driver package from Github and installed it; Can I delete this folder now?

Tags: networking, drivers, files, home-directory, github

I downloaded some network drivers from Github and now they are in my home folder. I have already installed them and my wifi works fine now. Can I safely delete this folder, or do I have to keep it to keep my network adapter working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely delete the folder and nothing will happens, the cloned folder contain nothing more than a installation script (usually a driver will have a makefile).

Neither of the driver file **should be** located on home directory, probably there are several who does it but this is highly unlikely— most of the time driver file are located on directory owned by root, and in no way a normal user would interfere without having root privilege.

So yeah, you can delete the file.

Comment: Driver files are never located in `/` root directory. Very few files are placed there with the exception of a few symbolic links that point to `/boot` directory. A simple "Yes you can delete it now" answer would have been better.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Bad wording on my side, I mean directory with root privileges, my bad.